# Android construct for chaining fragments together

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm looking to create a small flash card type element for my app.  I've looked at several solutions namely the [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) and it's parent the [FragmentPagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html).  Neither of these solve the problem I want to solve.  They deal with listviews of fragments.  I want to have a list of fragments that when I hit a button I move to the next one fragment in the list until I'm all done.

I've got all the saving the data part of it solved.  I just cannot figure out how to chain my fragments together.

To be explicit, what I'm looking for is:

a->b->c->d->done and go back to activity or a finished fragment.
The user would obviously use a button to progress from fragment to fragment.

I chose fragments because I figured that would be the easiest.  I'm not opposed to activities, but my problem is still largely the same.

I've tried implementing the FragmentPager stuff, but as I said it didn't suite my needs.

Comment: As I was writing this I think I might have another idea.  It would be a class that sort of oversees the fragments, but I haven't generalized it enough to work exactly as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this with a rather simple solution:

I have my activity which has some variables so that it knows what fragment it is on, along with that it inflates a layout with a framelayout and uses fragmentmanager transactions to replace given the fragment number we are on.  Then I have a parcelable class that defines the flashcard that is passed to each fragment upon instantiation.  On the activity's layout I have 3 buttons, "check", "correct", "incorrect" which, using View.GONE/View.VISIBLE am able to give the UI experience I want.  On the click of the "correct"/"incorrect" we start a transaction and move down the list to the next card.

The code:

```
    /**
     * The activity
     */
    public class VocabTestActivity extends Activity {

        private int mWordsCorrect = 0;
        private int mWordsIncorrect = 0;
        private int mCurrentPosition = 0;
        private ArrayList<Fragment> mCards = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        private final int FLAG_TOTAL_CARDS = 5;
        private GrammarDataSource mDataSource;

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_practice);

            final Button buttonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheckWordPractice);
            final Button buttonCorrect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCorrectWordPractice);
            final Button buttonIncorrect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonIncorrectWordPractice);
            final TextView textViewProgressBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewProgressBarPractice);

            this.mDataSource = new GrammarDataSource(this);

            this.initializeCards();

            buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    buttonCheck.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    buttonCorrect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buttonIncorrect.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            buttonCorrect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mWordsCorrect++;
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
                            R.id.practice_frame,
                            mCards.get(mCurrentPosition++)
                    ).commit();
                    buttonCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buttonCorrect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    buttonIncorrect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textViewProgressBar.setText(getString(R.string.practice_progress_bar, mCurrentPosition, FLAG_TOTAL_CARDS));
                }
            });

            buttonIncorrect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mWordsIncorrect++;
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
                            R.id.practice_frame,
                            mCards.get(mCurrentPosition++)
                    ).commit();
                    buttonCheck.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    buttonCorrect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    buttonIncorrect.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textViewProgressBar.setText(getString(R.string.practice_progress_bar, mCurrentPosition, FLAG_TOTAL_CARDS));
                }
            });
        }

        private void initializeCards() {
            for(VocabWord v : this.mDataSource.selectFlashCards(FLAG_TOTAL_CARDS)) {
                VocabTestFragment frag = VocabTestFragment.newInstance(new ParcelableWord(v));
                mCards.add(frag);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * The fragment
     */
    public class VocabTestFragment extends Fragment {

        private ViewGroup mRoot;
        public final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
        private VocabWord mWord;

        public static VocabTestFragment newInstance(ParcelableWord w) {
            VocabTestFragment frag = new VocabTestFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putParcelable("word", w);
            frag.setArguments(args);
            return frag;
        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            this.mRoot = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_practice_vocab, container, false);

            ItalianWord word = null;

            ParcelableWord pw = getArguments().getParcelable("word");
            pw.printIt();
            word = (ItalianWord) pw.getWord();

            TextView tv = (TextView) this.mRoot.findViewById(R.id.word);
            if(word != null) {
                tv.setText(word.getmId() + " is the id\t" + word.getmWord());
            } else {
                tv.setText("Word not provided");
            }

            return this.mRoot;
        }
    }

/**
 * fragment_practice_vocab
 */
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/word"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="placeholder"
        android:layout_weight="4" />

</LinearLayout>

/**
 * practice_activity
 */
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dip"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewProgressBarPractice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/practice_progress_bar"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/practice_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewProgressBarPractice"
        >

     </FrameLayout>



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCheckWordPractice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCorrectWordPractice"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Correct"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonIncorrectWordPractice"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Incorrect"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: There is obvious error handling missing, but the logic is what is important.

Answer (score 2):

How dynamic are the fragments you are making?  If there's a set amount of interchangeable elements,  you can try creating a delegate function in your main activity that opens fragments depending on a set of parameters.  Better still, you make your fragments modular so that you only have a few fragments with different states based on what you give them.

```
public void onCardWithIdSelected(int id, String param1, String param2, ...) {
    Fragment fragment = NULL;
    if(id == 0) {
        fragment = cardFragment.newInstanceFromParams(param1, param2, ...);  //this will pass the parameters onto the desired fragment
    }
    else if(id == 1) {
        fragment = cardFragment.newInstanceFromParams(param1, param2, ...);  //this will pass the parameters onto the desired fragment
    }
    else if(id == 2) {
        fragment = cardFragment.newInstanceFromParams(param1, param2, ...);  //this will pass the parameters onto the desired fragment
    }
    //and so on...
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null); //only do this if you don't want users to be able to go back

    // Commit the transaction
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Then whenever you want to move to a different fragment from one, you just call this function on the main activity with your desired parameters.